# AngularFire firebase cloud function return value problem

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, observable, angularfire

I have a problem with AngularFire, because in their github [(Documentation)](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md) it says it returns an Observable.

This is a new account on stackoverflow so i cant embedd the image here.

[code problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnqdm.png)

but the thing is that i cant subscribe to the Observable.

My guess is that it has to do something with the

```
(data: any) => Observable<any>;
```

because when i try to typedef the httpCallReleaseUser variable to an Observable. I get an error that tells me that it doesnt have the subscribe + some other methods.

[now with type definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcU0G.png)

if thats the problem

**What is the difference between**

```
Observable<any>
```

and

```
(data: any) => Observable<any>;
```

Comment: You are going to want to brush up on ES6 and then approach this problem

Comment: why not just tell me the correct answer ? i've seen these lambda functions before but why is the TYPE on the right side of the arrow ?

Comment: (a) => b in ES6 is the same as function(a){ b }

Comment: so in that specific case it would be function(data){ Observable }, how does  that make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This difference between `Observable` and `() => Observable` is that the latter is a function that outputs an `Observable`.

`AngularFireFunctions` has the signature `httpsCallable(name:string) => (data:any) => Observable<any>`, meaning you have to call it twice, first with the name of your function, and then again with the data you want to pass to the function.

`functions.httpsCallable('fn-name')({ ... your data here or empty })`

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is wrong.  As @Nelles indicates, you are doing a function, and that does not do what you want.  You likely want something simple like: 
`data:Observable<any>;` which says your variable is of an observable type.

You may need to get data in different formats, and even interfaces can be used. Maybe something like the following.

```
export class foo {
    private data:Observable<myInterface[]>;

    constructor(
        @Inject(AngularFireDatabase) protected AfDb: AngularFireDatabase,
    ) { }

    public get():Observable<myInterface[]> // Return an array of myInterface items as an observable. Note that the data in firebase needs to match myInterface, but fields will be supported automatically
    {
        data = this.AfDb.list<myInterface[]>('firebasetable').valueChanges()
        return data;
    }
}
```